# Can I use gcloud SDK on linux instance hosted with another cloud provider?

Tags: sdk, gcloud

I get:

Your "GCE" credentials are invalid. Please run
  $ gcloud auth login
Failure: GCE credentials requested outside a GCE instance.

keep doing it over again with same results. Migrated from GCE to cheaper provider, but still would like my linux instances be able to transfer files to Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Did you copy over your Cloud SDK installation and config during your migration?

Comment: yes I did. Initially it did not work at all due some Python errors, but after update everything seems to be ok except it does not want to authenticate.

Comment: try 'gcloud auth revoke' followed by 'gcloud auth login'

Comment: hmmm, no go after gcloud auth revoke

Comment: Ok...try deleting ~/.config/gcloud/gce .

Comment: did not work neither...

Comment: it starts to really acting on my nerves. I ended up removing entire SDK including ~/.config/gcloud/ and reinstalling it. Same error. Bad thing this instance produces a lot of content files I need to migrate to Google Cloud Storage or I will run out of space there soon. What else could this be?

Comment: when I run "gcloud compute instances list" it executes correctly tho.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing entire /root folder and upgrading python to 2.7 on CentOS. None of that helped. Turns out I had to install:

pip install -U crcmod

That finally solved the issue. Thanks guys for all your time and help. Hope this will save some time for next guy with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install and use Google Cloud SDKs on any machine inside or outside of the Google Cloud. You can download and install SDK on your desired platform from this link: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

After installation, use "gcloud auth login" command, enter the output link to your browser and login using your Google Cloud account, get the verification key and enter it to the field where command asks for.

Comment: I migrated working machine with rsync from google cloud. Its a CentOS system. I had to run yum update and reinstalled Google Cloud SDK. Did gcloud auth login but still getting Your "GCE" credentials are invalid. Please run
  $ gcloud auth login
Failure: GCE credentials requested outside a GCE instance.

Comment: do you get this error right away after running "gcloud auth login" command?  or after running another command?  Also, try this command: $ gsutil config -e

Comment: remove the old .boto files as well.

Comment: removed .boto reinstalled SDK. When I run gsutil config -e it said I had to install pyOpenSSL, which I did and re-run "gcloud auth login" still no go. I have it working on another instance, but this one migrated from Google Compute Engine with rsync just does not wanna cooperate. Im running out of ideas... "gcloud compute instances list" works fine and lists instances in the project. Just gcloud give me Your "GCE" credentials are invalid.

Comment: use "gcloud auth list", revoke all listed accounts using "gcloud auth revoke --all" , and authenticate again using "gcloud auth login". After doing this, make sure the active account is the one you're authenticated with.

Comment: still no go... I had only 1 account credentialed. Revoked and credentialed again. Same thing: No credentialed accounts. Again, its weird because this only happens with "gsutil mv". Other commands like "gcloud compute instances list" work fine and render results.